# `ifdef` keyword in middle of a statement is not highlighted in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The `ifdef` keyword in the middle of a statement is NOT highlighted pink in `vscode`, while those at the start are highlighted so. Why does this happen ?

```
class TestClass {
    int m_x;
    #ifdef FLAG  // This ifdef keyword is highlighted
    int m_variable_used_when_flag_enabled;
    #endif
    TestClass(int x) : m_x(x) 
    #ifdef FLAG // This ifdef keyword is NOT highlighted
        ,m_variable_used_when_flag_enabled() 
    #endif
        {
            
        }
};
```

Comment: they have different TextMate scopes, see issue, it does not expect an #ifdef inside the function definition head

Comment: So, this is a bug right ? Sorry, I am not aware of TextMate scopes ..

Comment: I haven't looked at the TextMate file for C++, but it does not give the same construct the same scope so it is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine on Xcode and Sublime Text. So it's an editor's limitation and you may file a bug on VSCode's GitHub repo.

Also, note that the comma should be in the conditional, not outside it. It causes a compile error.

```
class TestClass {
  int m_x;
#ifdef FLAG  // This ifdef keyword is highlighted
  int m_variable_used_when_flag_enabled;
#endif
  TestClass(int x)
      : m_x(x)
#ifdef FLAG  // This ifdef keyword is NOT highlighted
        ,
        m_variable_used_when_flag_enabled()
#endif
  {
  }
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the comma at wrong place was a typo once I was making a smaller reproducible issue